# I need to split an array of data into cells in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, split, excel-2016, vba

I have a spreadsheet that queries a data source and returns an array of about 230 rows of comma separated results. The data looks like this:

[image: Existing Data]

I need to have all those comma separated values that are now in one cell (column B) split into separate cells. There are typically 21 results for each row. So the result should look like this:

[image: Desired Result]

The row the data starts on could vary, but typically starts around row 80. The top rows are used for displaying results from the data below it. The starting point could be fixed at say row 120 (if that makes scripting easier), which would leave plenty of room for future dev.

I've tried modifying a few different solutions I've found on here, but none worked. Any help is supremely appreciated!

Comment: Copy the comma separated data into notepad and use find and replace to replace all the commas with TABs. copy and paste it back into Excel and it will put the values into separate cells.

Comment: Just use Data>Text to columns and separate on the commas. No need to export the data to notepad etc. If you'd rather a vba solution loop through the cells that need to be split and use the `Split` function and write that array back to your sheet

Comment: Put `0,0` into A1 on a blank worksheet and go through TextToColumns, Delimited, Comma, Finish. Clear A1 and B1. Paste the data from its source into A1. It should split properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help and pointing in the right direction. Here's what I've ended up using:

```
Sub Expand_Array_On_New_Sheet

'  First check that new sheet name doesn't already exist, and create sheet

   Sheet_name_to_create = Sheet10.Range("B1").Value
   If WorksheetExists2(Sheet10.Range("B1")) Then
      MsgBox "Sheet name already exists"
  Exit Sub
  Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet_name_to_create
  End If

'  Copy array data to new sheet

    Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A11:B250").Copy
    Range("A101").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'  Expand Array Data into Columns and do some formatting

   Range("B101:B350").Select
   Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C101"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
       :=",", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   Range("C100").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-98]C[-1]-19"
   Range("D100").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+1"
   Range("D100").Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D100:V100"), Type:=xlFillDefault
   Range("W100").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current"
   Range("C100:W100").Select
   With Selection.Interior
       .Pattern = xlSolid
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
       .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
       .PatternTintAndShade = 0
   End With
   Selection.Font.Bold = True
   With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
       .LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .ColorIndex = 0
       .TintAndShade = 0
       .Weight = xlMedium
   End With
   Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
   Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
   Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
   Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

It seems to work well. The lingering issue I'm running into is that if the data set is less than 21 entries (most are 21, but not all), the last column of data ends up at column T or V or something. I need the last entry to always be in column W, and fill backwards. I probably need to search that as a separate question.

Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to do what you want with Excel's Text To Columns feature explained [at this link](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html). You can re-write individual rows or big blocks of them in one click. I draw your attention especially to the parameter on the third tab where you can define a destination for the data, such as the B120 you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I've now used that, recorded it, and incorporated it into a script. Posting solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully test this but maybe you can try something like this. The procedure should iterate through the rows and split out the values in column B.

You will need to change the name of "Sheet1" in `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to the name of the worksheet you are using.

```
Public Sub SplitData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim row As Integer
    For row = 1 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        Dim split_array() As String
        split_array = Split(ws.Range("B" & row).Value, ",")
        Dim split_str As Variant
        Dim col As Integer
        col = 3
        For Each split_str In split_array
            ws.Cells(row, col).Value = split_str
            col = col + 1
        Next split_str

    Next row

End Sub
```

My sheet started out looking like this.

[image]

It ended up looking like this after running the procedure.

[image]

Comment: That gave me the error: "Type Mismatch" at the Split Array command. I've been messing with it for a couple of hours now and came up with a clunky solution using the macro recorder in excel. I'll post the resulting sub. It's not elegant, but it's working...for now.

Comment: That's weird I tried a couple different scenarios but couldn't seem to get the "Type Mismatch" error. If you could post in a comment exactly which line throws the error and what the data was in column B for that given row. Given that I could probably figure out why it would throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a very simple way of doing this.

- Cut all the comma separated data and paste it into a txt file. In your case it should start from Column B (row 120 or whatever it is)
- In data tab, click "From Text" and open your text file
- Select delimited with comma separated option and click next
- When you click finish, excel asks for the cell in which the data has to be pasted. Give the required cell name that you want your data. In your case it can be B120.

Now you got what you wanted. Better take a backup of your worksheet in case you corrupt the data accidentally